# Spring ClassPathXmlApplicationContext cannot load xml

Tags: spring

I want to load applicationContext xml by ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.
I use this method can load

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-context.xml");
```

but After I create a folder, Spring can't load applicationContext

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("venom/spring/study/spring-context.xml");
```

[this is my module struct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FU0TI.png)

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you need to specify the path as long as those folders are inside resources folder, you just need to specify the XML file name like this:

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-context.xml");
```